# Hibernate message that table is not mapped though it is

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have this table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `realEstate`.`USER` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `registrationDate` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `registered` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`userID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and I try to get all its contents with hibernate. Althoug I implemented the .hbm file I get the error that `the USER is not mapped[from USER]`. Here how I make the question:

```
List<Users> users = null;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from USER");
            users = query.list();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception:");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            /*for(Users user:users){
                System.out.println(user.getName());
            }*/
        }
        System.out.println("Complete");
```

and here is the users.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Users" table="USER">
        <id name="userID" type="int">
            <column name="userID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="username" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="password" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name" length="45"/>
        </property>
         <property name="date" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="registrationDate" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="surname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="surname" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="phone" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="email" length="45"/>
        </property>
        <property name="registered" type="boolean">
            <column name="registered" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Eveyrything seems fine to me, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Here's the class Users:

```
public class Users {
    private int user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String date;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private boolean registered;

    public int getuserID() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setuserID(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public boolean getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }
    public void setRegistered(boolean registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }

}
```

here's the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="session1">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/realestate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping resource="users.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="adminstrator.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here's the directory

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, your users.hbm.xml file is read and processed by hibernate? Do you have other mappings that work or its your single mapping? Could you please post a configuration code?

Comment: @MarkBramnik   users.hbm.xml file is at the same folder with the hibernate.cfg.xml(that has the mapping resource property)  so I assume that it is read. This is my only mapping. What do you mean configuration code?

Comment: I tested it for another Table and I still get the same results

Comment: maybe you should post hibernate.cfx.xml as well here, BTW where exactly did you put it?

Comment: @MarkBramnik I updated the question. Have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `HQL` , you should use the java class name and property name of the mapped `Entity` instead of the actual table name and column name , so the `HQL` should be :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from USERS");
```

as provided by you in `users.hbm.xml`

Comment: You are my hero! Thx a lot. I would never found it out on my own!

Comment: @JmRag It's just that it strike me at the first place, else everybody is hero here who are taking there time out to help everyone.